# How to randomly navigate to other fragments?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I have 20 fragments. I want to navigate fragments randomly with a button.It works correctly but I don't want to revisit the same fragments. If I navigate from fragment 5 to 9, I don't want to re-navigate to 5 anymore. I want to see every fragment just once. In every fragment I did this:

```
btnNavigateNewFragment.setOnClickListener {
val list: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(
                R.id.nav_new_game_eighteen,
                R.id.nav_dealgame,
                R.id.nav_new_game_one,
                R.id.nav_new_game_two,
                R.id.nav_new_game_three,
                R.id.nav_new_game_four,
                R.id.nav_new_game_five,
                R.id.nav_new_game_six,
                R.id.nav_new_game_seven,
                R.id.nav_new_game_eight,
                R.id.nav_new_game_nine,
                R.id.nav_new_game_ten,
                R.id.nav_new_game_eleven,
                R.id.nav_new_game_twelve,
                R.id.nav_new_game_thirteen,
                R.id.nav_new_game_fourteen,
                R.id.nav_new_game_fifteen,
                R.id.nav_new_game_sixteen,
                R.id.nav_new_game_seventeen
            )
val randomFragment= list.random()
findNavController().navigate(randomFragment)
```

What logic should I use to not visit the fragment that navigated once ?

Comment: Remove picked fragment from list and after that navigate to that fragment.`list.remove(randomFragment)`

Comment: In an Activity-scoped ViewModel, keep a Mutable set of the visited Fragments and subract them from this List before picking the random value.

Comment: @GurgenArustamyan Thanks for comment. If am in fragment 3 currently, should I remove the id of fragment 3 from the list ? But it is still possible to navigate back to fragment 3 in other fragments. Should I save that list to a shared preferences ?

Comment: You can define list in activity and it will be same for all fragments or define it in shared viewModel or yes, you can save it in sharedPref. But I think best option is to define it in activity

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for your comment. Can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep track of the visited fragments in an Activity-scoped ViewModel. If you keep it in a Fragment or Activity property, it will be lost if there's a configuration change.

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val destinations = listOf(
                R.id.nav_new_game_eighteen,
                R.id.nav_dealgame,
                R.id.nav_new_game_one,
                //...
                R.id.nav_new_game_seventeen
        )

    private val remainingDestinations = mutableListOf<Int>().apply { addAll(destinations) }

    fun getNextNavDestination(): Int {
        if (remainingDestinations.isEmpty()) {
            remainingDestinations.addAll(destinations)
            // or whatever logic you want to do when all destinations have been used
        }
        val destination = remainingDestinations.random()
        remainingDestinations.remove(destination)
        return destination
    }
}
```

In your fragment that goes to one of the random destinations:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val myViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //...

        btnNavigateNewFragment.setOnClickListener {
            indNavController().navigate(myViewModel.getNextNavDestination())
        }
    }
}
```